# 'tabular' environment-Changing column separator character

Tags: tables

I want to change column separator symbol '&' of tabular environment by creating a new environment that also works similar to tabular environment.
Please Help.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/new-users-how-to-do-good-questions-and-answers).

Comment: i would not do this. if you will still persist in your idea, you need to provide more information, what you try so far and where you stuck in your efforts. so far your question is unclear ...

Comment: To accomplish this, I tried working with \pgfplotstable package that I found as an answer at this site for the similar questions. However, the error poped up by inly accepting 1.16 as comat value and nothing else.

Comment: @NamanAgarwal (1) Please link that answer to this question. (2) I suggest: **Don't do it!!!!** (3) Possible duplicate of [Use comma instead of & in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477714/156344).